# Is every projection of an integrable function also integrable.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, multivariable-calculus

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfy $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f(x) d \lambda^n(x) < \infty.$ For a unit vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$, define the projection of $f$ onto span($v$) as $f_v(r) := f(r \cdot v)$.
Is it true that $\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_v(s)ds < \infty$ for all $v?$

If not, is there a simple counterexample?

Thank you.

Comment: With $n=2$ take $f=0$ except $f=1$ on the $x$ axis. Then the integral on the plane is zero, but the integral on the ray is does not exist.

Comment: Thank you! On the one hand this makes sense but on the other hand I'm wondering why this is not violating Fubini's Theorem. Wouldn't we have $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}f(x,y) d\lambda^2= \int_\mathbb{R}\int_\mathbb{R}f(x,y) dx dy = \int_\mathbb{R} \infty dy = \infty$?

Comment: @maiktheissen It is only $\int_{\Bbb{R}}f(x,0)\,dx=\int_{\Bbb{R}}1\,dx=\infty$. For any $y\neq 0$, we have $\int_{\Bbb{R}}f(x,y)\,dx=\int_{\Bbb{R}}0\,dx=0$. So, if you do it carefully, Fubini just says $0=0=0$ (double integral equals the two iterated integrals).

Comment: What you can say is the following: suppose $f\geq 0$ is integrable on $\Bbb{R}^n$. Then, by a change of variables to polar coordinates, $\int_{\Bbb{R}^n}f(x)\,d\lambda^n(x)=\int_{S^{n-1}}\int_0^{\infty}f(rv)\cdot r^{n-1}\,dr\,d\sigma(v)$ is finite, so for $\sigma$-a.e $v\in S^{n-1}$, we have that $\int_0^{\infty}f(rv)\cdot r^{n-1}\,dr<\infty$. Here, $\sigma$ is the surface measure on the unit sphere $S^{n-1}\subset\Bbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately I still don't see my mistake. According to wikipedia Fubini (with Tonelli) says that for $\sigma$-finite measure spaces $X$ and $Y$ we have $\int_{X\times Y}f(x,y) d(x,y) = \int_Y (\int_X f(x,y) dx)) dy$. Now if I choose $X$ as the X-axis (i.e span $(0,1)^T$) and $Y$ as the Y-axis (i.e span $(1,0)^T$), then I can write $\mathbb{R}^2$ as $X\times Y$, right? Now $\int_X f(x,y) dx= \int_X f(x,0) = \infty$, as you said. But then  $\int_{XxY}f(x,y) d(x,y) =\int_Y \infty dy$. Where did I go wrong here?

Comment: \begin{align}
\int_{\Bbb{R}^2}f(x,y)\,d\lambda_2(x,y)&=\int_{\Bbb{R}}\int_{\Bbb{R}}f(x,y)\,dx\,dy\tag{Tonelli}\\
&=\int_{\{0\}}\int_{\Bbb{R}}f(x,y)\,dx\,dy+ \int_{\Bbb{R}\setminus\{0\}}\int_{\Bbb{R}}f(x,y)\,dx\,dy\\
&=\int_{\{0\}}\infty\,dy + \int_{\Bbb{R}\setminus\{0\}}0\,dy\\
&=\infty\cdot \lambda_1(\{0\})+0\\
&=\infty\cdot 0+0\\
&=0,
\end{align}
where $\infty\cdot 0=0$ is the standard convention in measure theory.

Comment: The error you're making is that there is only one single value of $y$ for which the integral is infinite, $\int_{X}f(x,0)\,dx=\int_{\Bbb{R}}f(x,0)\,dx=\int_{\Bbb{R}}1\,dx=\infty$. However, the singleton set $\{0\}\subset \Bbb{R}$ has measure zero, so integrating over all the $y$'s still gives 0.